# Exclude files with Ant

Tags: php, ant, build

i'm creating a PHP project and i'd wish to distribuite 2 version: a free one and a pro one.

Enhanced features are all inside some files, so i only have to "skip" them to create the free version.
My question is: which is the best way to achieve that?
i can list every file in the build.xml file (they are 20 at max), but it's pretty ugly, moreover if i forgot to update the list i will ad these files...

i thought about using the `contains` keyword, but it will slow my build?

**EDIT**
This is my build.xml file:

```
<project name="MyProject" default="build" basedir=".">
<property name="buildDir"   value="${basedir}/build"/>
<property name="componente" value="${basedir}/trunk/componente"/>
<property name="backend"    value="${componente}/backend"/>
<property name="frontend"   value="${componente}/frontend"/>

<target name="build" depends="cleanup, pro, free" />

<!-- Clean up the build directory output -->
<target name="cleanup">
    <echo>Clean up build directory</echo>
    <delete includeemptydirs="true">
        <fileset dir="${buildDir}" includes="**/*"/>
    </delete>
</target>

<!-- Create the pro package (no file exclusion) -->
<target name="pro">
    <echo>Build pro version</echo>
    <zip destfile="${buildDir}/pro.zip" basedir="${componente}" />
</target>

<!-- Create the free package (file exclusion) -->
<target name="free">
    <echo>Build free version</echo>
</target>
```

**EDIT 2**
My pro files are in different folders and i can't move them since i'm using the MVC pattern

Comment: Have you tried? Did it work? Did it slow down your build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i found it.
i added a PHPDoc tag into my exclude files:
`@category   ProPackage`

then i added these rules in my build.xml

```
<target name="free">
    <zip destfile="${buildDir}/pro.zip">
        <fileset dir="${componente}">
            <not>
                <containsregexp expression="@category[ \t]+ProPackage"/>
            </not>
        </fileset>
    </zip>
</target>
```

And it's done!

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [Ant Manual](https://ant.apache.org/manual/):

> The zip task forms an implicit FileSet and supports most attributes of `<fileset>` (dir becomes basedir) as well as the nested `<include>`, `<exclude>` and `<patternset>` elements.

Which means you can do

```
<zip destfile="${buildDir}/free.zip"
     basedir="${componente}"
     excludes="**/features/pro/**, **/other/**"/>
```

Regarding

> EDIT 2 My pro files are in different folders and i can't move them since i'm using the MVC pattern

MVC is not about folder layout at all. [It's about roles and responsibilities](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/modelViewController.html). It says nothing about where to put files. Some frameworks conventionalize where to put class files, but as long as your autoloader can find the class files, it really doesnt matter where they are: so yes, you can move them.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use filesets :

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html

```
<fileset dir="${files.directory}" casesensitive="yes">
  <include name="**/*free.php"/>
  <exclude name="**/*pro.php"/>
</fileset>
```

Of course you have to provide different names in the include/exclude elements. Ideally you could separate the pro stuff to a different file and simply exclude the whole directory.

Comment: yep, i know, but it's quite error prone, since my files aren't in the same directory & i tend to forget things :P

Comment: @tampe125 Ehm you need to organize things then. This is the default ant mechanism to exclude / include files. You can even use other criteria such as file contents or date of modification etc but eventually you will have to use this task.

Comment: yes, but i'm using the MVC pattern, so things are splitted in several folders.